# Split string separated by comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-server-2017

which is the best way to separate a string separated by comma and take each single value?
example

```
@variable = john,emma,walter, ... , dallas,
```

then take the single value like...

```
john
emma
walter
...
dallas
```

I need each value to dynamically create a select statement like:

```
select * from tableName where john = ... and emma = ... //etc...
```

Thank you all

Solution [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns) is different because it spit into column... i need to use each value for a select/where statement...

Comment: use `string_split()` function

Comment: Which version of the SQL Server?

Comment: Wait, you're trying to check if the *column* `john` has a value of *something* and the column `emma` has the value *something*, etc, not if a column has the value `'John'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: What does `last` version means? SQL Server 2017 or SQL Server 2019 RC? And what will be the last version when some open your question after few years?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5493510/3484879), ***if*** OP actually wants `[Column] = 'John'` and not `[John] = {some value}`.

Comment: for Larnu, the name are all primary key of a table, so i need it to create the where condition in the select statement... after the = are the value

Comment: Sample data and expected results would really help here, as I really don't understand what you mean by `where john =`. Where is the column `John` coming from? If it's coming from the delimited data, where is the **value** for `John` coming from? You delimited list isn't a CSV.

Comment: So you have the primary key which is made up of the ***columns*** `John`, `emma`, `walter`, `dallas`, etc? That sounds like a huge design flaw. Normally a Primary Key is a single column, or at most 2, which as a combination make a composite primary key. For example, `OrderID` and `StockID`, which contains a column `Quantity` in a "joining" table for a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: As @Larnu said, please edit your question to include sample data as _formatted text or DDL and DML or better create a fiddle_ and not **images**, and provide the expected results. As it is now we can't understand what's the issue and what 're trying to achieve.

Comment: SQL Server 2017 already has [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for this. You can loop over the returned values to generate the statement or you can explain what that statement actually does, since it's quite likely there are *better* options.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - that's if he has access to 2017 or better...

Comment: @Paul the question says `SQL Server 2017`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Duh! Yep - missed that - not having the best day today! [rollseyes]

Comment: why for this downvote ? i didn't found a solution in google so i ask here, i didn't found another similar question here.... can you please take off the down vote? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use variable table and join with it

```
Declare @SplitDate Table(
    DataValue NVARCHAR(100)
)
DECLARE @variable NVARCHAR(MAX)  = 'john,emma,walter,dallas'
INSERT INTO @SplitDate(DataValue)

SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@variable, ',');


SELECT * FROM @SplitDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn your condition the other way round.  What you should be searching for is...

```
WHERE 
    ',' + 'john,paul,ringo,george' + ',' LIKE '%,' + myfield + ',%'
```

Note that I appended the extra sets of speech marks so you could use a list from a variable, e.g.

```
WHERE 
    ',' + @mylist + ',' LIKE '%,' + myfield + ',%'
```

Comment: Maybe you mean `'%,' + MyColumn + ',%'` no?

Comment: @Sami - Yes - just missed those in my haste!